# android - sqlite getReadableDatabase() error

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am a beginner and I want to use SQLITE but I got error.
this function is inside the main class:

```
public Cursor getData(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from weight where id="+id+"", null );
    return res;
 }
```

I imported the sqlite files:

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
```

the errror is:
The method getReadableDatabase() is undefined for the type Activity3

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Implement a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`, providing the required `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` lifecycle callbacks.
2. Call `getReadableDatabase()` on your database helper object and not on the activity, e.g.

   ```
   SQLiteDatabaseHelper helper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
   SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
   ```

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your cursor instead:

```
Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(Uri, 
projection,selection,selectionArgs,sortOrder);
```

now you wont have to call the SQLiteDatabase object which keeps producing null.

Comment: StackOverflow discourages code only answers. Can you click on edit and add a summary of why this piece of code works for you? It will be more helpful to others that way.